# Using piezo buzzer to play complex waveforms

Tags: piezo-buzzer

Would it be possible to play complex waveforms(sine waves, triangular waves, multiple voices and suchlike) using a normal piezo buzzer? The buzzer in question doesn't have internal oscillator. [[Datasheet]](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/84905.pdf)

I have only ever seen piezo buzzers used to emit square waves(via PWM) and speakers with magnets to play more complex waves/music. Is there some inherent flaw in piezo buzzers that makes it unsuitable for playing complex waves/multiple voicings?

I intend to use an R-2R ladder DAC on a SI-PO shift resistor driven by an ATtiny13 to create waveforms to drive the buzzer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would it be possible to play complex waveforms(sine waves, triangular waves, multiple voices and suchlike) using a normal piezo buzzer?

No. While you technically can use piezo crystals to make very fine, arbitrary movements (actuators for microscopes etc do that), your buzzer will effectively only work when excited by something that is periodic and hits its own resonance.

Comment: Well if OP has a very very very good hearing (s)he might actually hear something :P

Comment: Most piezo transducers are shriekers and squeakers, not speakers. They do not play medium and low audio frequencies and the frequencies they do play have levels all over the place.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, You ABSOLUTELY CAN play complex waveforms. I have.

We used a Texas Instruments DRV2700 to drive a large-diameter piezo. We designed a helmholtz resonator at the piezo's resonant frequency (~1200Hz), to get the "alert" volume up to around 120dB. Then swept the frequency range, inversed the response, overlayed it on the audio file we wanted to output, and played it. The Audio will not be good. But you hear "fire in the Master Bedroom" clear enough.

Check out the 7NB-31R2-1 from murata. And remember, this is a voltage device not a current device like a speaker coil.